# XPath to find text node that is a sibling of other nodes

Tags: xpath

Given the following fragment of html:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>My Legend</legend>
  <p>Some text</p>
  Text to capture
</fieldset>
```

Is there an xpath expression that will return only the 'Text to capture' text node?

Trying

```
/fieldset/text()
```

yields three nodes, not just the one I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming what you want is the text node containing non whitespace text :

```
//fieldset/text()[normalize-space(.)]
```

If what you want is the last text node, then:

```
//fieldset/text()[last()]
```

Comment: The `.` is optional for `normalize-space()`, when no argument given it operates on the context node.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you accept Steven D. Majewski's answer, but here is the explanation (text nodes highlighted with square brackets):

```
<fieldset>[
  ]<legend>My Legend</legend>[
  ]<p>Some text</p>[
  Text to capture
]</fieldset>
```

so `/fieldset/text()` returns

- `"\n  "`
- `"\n  "`
- `"\n  Text to capture\n"`

And this is why you want `/fieldset/text()[normalize-space()]`, and you want the result trimmed before use.

Also note that the above is short for `/fieldset/text()[normalize-space(.) != '']`. When `normalize-space()` returns a non-empty string, the predicate evaluates to `true`, while the empty string evaluates to `false`.